# Looking for an expression

Tags: phrase-requests, academic-writing

I'm looking for a better way to say that once a new kind of virus is discovered, various gene analysis methods, such as A B C, are already in stock (or at hand) to be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you requesting a paraphrase of the whole of *once a new kind of virus is discovered, various gene analysis methods, such as A B C, are already in stock (or at hand) to be used.*? Or only one part of it?

Comment: When a new type of virus is discovered, various existing gene-analysis methods will be used.

Comment: @Greybeard I wish to have a concise and formal way to say this sentence, especially the latter part "various analysis methods are already in stock to be used." Thanks.

Comment: @RamPillai 'various existing gene-analysis method' is neat! Thank you!